# zend framework 3, multiple db tables in one controller

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

I have a ZF3 project and an index controller that accesses a single postgres table.  I have the usual factories setup

```
return array(
        'factories' => [
            Model\IsdepotstockTable::class => function($container) {
                $tableGateway = $container->get(Model\IsdepotstockTableGateway::class);
                return new Model\IsdepotstockTable($tableGateway);
            },
            Model\IsdepotstockTableGateway::class => function ($container) {
                $dbAdapter = $container->get(AdapterInterface::class);
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Model\Isdepotstock());
                return new TableGateway('isdepotstock', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
            },
        ],
```

I also have my controller constructor thus:

```
public function __construct(IsdepotstockTable $table)
{
    $this->isdepotstockTable = $table;
}
```

My question is, if I wish to access a second table, how do I modify the construct statement to handle multiple tables?  Obviously I have to add the factories for the additional table that much I understand.

I've looked through the ZF3 documentation but cannot find any example.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking for a controller factory function which will instantiate the controller and pass the arguments to the constructor.

Add your second table class as the 2nd argument in the `__construct()` method, then create your factory in `module.config.php`.

```
<?php
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory;

return [
    // ...

    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\IndexController::class => InvokableFactory::class
            // Put other controllers registration here
        ],
    ],

    // ...
];
```

Here is a free open source book on ZF3, I link to the controller registration section for your reference. Good luck! https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/Model_View_Controller/Controller_Registration.html